# Posted Firebase security rules as example are incorrect

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

i received an email stating that the rules are insecure which is appreciated but following the documentation and trying to apply one of the rules i received all kinds of errors so hopefully someone will be able to help me here since i couldn't find a way to communicate with google-firebase.

Further to that trying to post feedback on the page to be corrected the feedback asks for a screenshot which can be taken only on the same page? it might be something on my browser set by default to not allow that? i will check on that but until then here are the rules and the errors so maybe someone can let me know what is incorrect on this page under mixed public and private access for Realtime Database: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/insecure-rules

```
{
    // Allow anyone to read data, but only authenticated content owners can
    // make changes to their data

    "rules": {
    "some_path/${uid}": {
        ".read": true
        // or ".read": "auth.uid != null" for only authenticated users
        ".write": "request.auth.uid == uid"
    }
  }
}
```

Simulation failed - Line 9: Expected ',' or '}'.

removed the comments and then got this error:

```
{
    "rules": {
    "some_path/${uid}": {
        ".read": true
        ".write": "request.auth.uid == uid"
    }
  }
}
```

thank you for your help
with the rule in this format as suggested

```
{
   "rules": {
        "propco-test": {
            "$uid": {
                ".read": true,
                ".write": "request.auth.uid == $uid"
            }
        }
   }
}
```

the error is:
Simulation failed - Line 6: Unknown variable 'request

Comment: The rules are missing a `,` after the `".read": true`, which makes them invalid JSON. If you add that the error should disappear. I recommend running the rules though a JSON validator to catch syntax errors like this. I also filed a bug to get that fixed in the documentation, so hopefully it'll be fixed there too soon.

Comment: i tried that before and forgot to mention. it gives this error: Simulation failed - Line 6: Key names can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]" (unbound names start with "$") . I will also try with a json validator. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, this is not a valid syntax: `"some_path/${uid}":`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for your help. It still doesn't work in the format posted bellow by you complaining about the same (Line 8: String can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"). I'm completely at lost with these rules.  on another account exactly the same settings and it stopped receiving the insecure rules. anywhere where someone can get educated on these rules? as it seems the documentation is very cryptic(for newbies) and when tested in some case not even working. appreciated

Comment: That error message should disappear with the structure in my answer below. The documentation bug you found has been fixed. If you find similar issues please provide a link. The documentation where you found the problem is the best we have on the topic. I find it not as much cryptic, as just an unusual syntax. If you run into another concrete problem, please post a question with your rules, and the code that is not working against it.

Comment: i changed "some_path" with my valid path "propco-test" and the error now is Line 6: Unknown variable 'request'. i was able to write an app in java and one for android to work with it prior to these security rules. I know they are not secure at all but cannot get to change these security rules on the Realtime database. afterwards i will change the login application even tough it's user/password based. But first these rules. Thanks for your support.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following what the new problem is. If you have applied the fix I mentioned below, and are getting another problem, please post a new question with a new [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i update my initial question with the latest info provided which brings a new error

Comment: I updated my answer, but as said: you should really post a new question when you have another problem. My answer explained the structure of your rules, and the next problem was about trying to use a non-existing variable. I've updated my answer to also show how to fix that, but in general: please open a new question if you have more problems after applying the fix in an answer.

Comment: this was the answer which would allow me to add these rules. so this is correct now. my other questions would be posted once i formalize them. this is a closed item. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `"some_path/${uid}"` in your rules are not valid. If you want to have rules for `some_path/$uid` that'd look like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "some_path": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [`$` wildcard variables in security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#wildcard_capture_variables).

---

**Edit**: `request` is not a variable in Realtime Database security rules, so I removed that from my answer. I noticed this was also a mistake in the documentation, so I submitted a fix for that which should be published in the next few days.

Comment: hello, i think they have still not updated the google documentation yet on that part..
So i have a question regarding this code for example the "some_path":    that can be to specify a path in our root folder from our app? if so how can we apply this?

Comment: Given that I submitted the fix and published it, I'm pretty sure it made it in. :)   That said, if you have a problem with/question about security rules, I recommend opening a new question with its own [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).